# Replacing a max constraint in a binary program

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

For $x \in \{0,1\}$, I want to express $x = 1 \Leftrightarrow \exists k: y_k = 2$ where $y_k \in \{0,1,2\}$, i.e. $x \leq 0.5\max_k\{y_k\}$ using binary decision variables but I can't figure out how to do it.

$x \geq 0.5(y_k-1)$ ensures $x=1$ if $y_k = 2$, but I need if and only if.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'll answer my own question in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split x in 3 parts, like $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \{0,1\}^3$, set $x=x_1+x_2+x_3$ and put the following constraint with $y_k \in \{0,1,2 \}$ :
$$ 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 $$
$$ x_k ≥ (y_k-1), \ \forall k $$